# Query not Echoing Out

Tags: php, mysql

The code below should echo out the total number of messages less than 24 hours old where `recipient = '$u'`, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Any idea why not?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
  $sqlStrw = "SELECT COUNT(*) newmessages
  FROM PRIVATEMESSAGE pm
 WHERE pm.datesent >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND recipient = '$u'";


  $resultw = mysql_query($sqlStrw);

$arrw = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrecw\">";
while ($roww = mysql_fetch_array($resultw)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="border:5px solid #FF8F20;" class="sitename5pw">'.$roww["newmessages"].'new1</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error if you do `var_dump(mysql_error());` after the query call?

Comment: Have you tried this query in phpMyAdmin (or other client) to see if results are returned?

Comment: @lonesomeday When I add `var_dump(mysql_error());` I get `string(0) ""`

Comment: do `if ($resultw === FALSE) { die(mysql_error()); }` immediately after the `mysql_query()` call. Never EVER assume your query succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a slight error in your original query. You're missing the "AS" from the top line so the row won't be pulling as you expect, it should look like this:

```
$sqlStrw = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS newmessages
  FROM PRIVATEMESSAGE pm
 WHERE pm.datesent >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND recipient = '$u'";
```

Best thing to do when these queries don't work is use something like phpMyAdmin to test the query and see what results are being returned.

Comment: Actually, best thing to do is never ever assume the query succeeded and do the appropriate checks after each query call. Even if the sql is perfectly valid, there's a zillion other reasons the call will fail.

Comment: From the mysql docs: "The AS keyword is optional when aliasing a select_expr with an identifier"..so shouldn't be the problem here?

Comment: I was going to add a small bit on `mysql_error()`, but the fundamentals had already been covered in the comments on the original question.

Comment: @Oli: Really? Sorry, I always assumed it was explicit.